# $\lim_{n \to \infty}(1/(n^3+1)+1/(n^3+2)+...+1/5n^3)=\ln5$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, riemann-sum

How do I show that $$\lim_{n \to \infty}(1/(n^3+1)+1/(n^3+2)+...+1/5n^3)=\ln 5$$ I know this can be done using an integral but for this particular question I cannot simply find an equivalent Riemann sum.Any answers will be welcomed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an increment of $\frac1{n^3}$
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{4n^3}\frac1{n^3+k}
&=\sum_{k=1}^{4n^3}\frac{1/n^3}{1+k/n^3}\\
&\sim\int_0^4\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+x}
\end{align}
$$
where $x\sim k/n^3$ and $\mathrm{d}x\sim1/n^3$

Comment: why is the integration taken from 0 to 4?

Comment: @user81883: since $x\sim k/n^3$ and $k$ goes from $1$ to $4n^3$.